# Complex T-SQL Statement

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am not the best SQL programmer so I am basically asking someone for help writing a query that will get my desired result. Here is the table structure for the scope of the query.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblOverNightPermissions] (
[DateAndTime] DATETIME       NULL,
[Address]     NVARCHAR (200) NULL,
[Direction]   NVARCHAR (102) NULL,
[NoOfDays]    INT            NULL,
[UserID]      INT            NOT NULL,
[OverNightID] INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Exempt]      INT            NULL,
[Beat]        INT            NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PrimaryKey_1fd244dd-bfd8-4998-8439-4d7d7893d387] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([OverNightID] ASC),
CONSTRAINT [FK_tblOverNightPermissions_0] FOREIGN KEY ([UserID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[tblUsers] ([UserID])
```

);

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblOverNightToVehicles] (
[OverNightID] INT NOT NULL,
[VehicleID]   INT NOT NULL,
[ID]          INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PrimaryKey_b433eaad-fb12-493c-9302-3f3bd9bd74e3] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC),
CONSTRAINT [FK_tblOverNightToVehicles_0] FOREIGN KEY ([OverNightID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[tblOverNightPermissions] ([OverNightID]) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT [FK_tblOverNightToVehicles_1] FOREIGN KEY ([VehicleID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[tblVehicles] ([VehicleID]) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

);

What I want to do is select record from tblOverNightPermissions and group them by month. I also want to count the number of records for that month and grouped by the vehicle ID which is in tblOverNightToVehicles. The goal is to run a check to make sure there have not been more than 5 overnightpermissions per vehicle id per month. It gets kind of tricky because the database design is not sound. As you can see, the `NoOfDays` field in the tblOvernightPermissions makes things complicated. Instead of there always being a set number of records per month, users have the ability to select up to 5 consecutive days of parking. So if I park today and select 5 days my record entry will look like this
    DateAndTime = 5/8/2014
    Address = x
    Direction = S
    NoOfDays = 5
    UserId = 1
    OvernightId = 1
    Exempt = 0
    Beat = 2

That means, for the month I will only have one physical record in tblOverNightPermissions that represents 5 days of parking. I could just as easily create 5 records in the table to signify 5 days of parking and thats where the issue comes in. Writing conditionals in TSQL to take into account if a record has NoOfDays > 1 add that to the count of the physical records for the month.

**Here are the scripts to populate your databases**

Script to populate tblOvernightPermissions https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/62170850/tblOvernightPermissions.txt

Script to populate tblOvernightToVehicles
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/62170850/tblOverNightToVehicles.txt

Comment: Could you show sample data and desired output in simple table format for those of us too lazy to read?  It also helps clarify what you're after, not just about me being lazy.

Comment: Did even better. Gave you scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, p.DateAndTime), 0) AS [Month],
     SUM(p.NoOfDays) As Days
FROM tblOverNightPermissions p
INNER JOIN tblOverNightToVehicles v ON p.OverNightID = v.OverNightID
GROUP BY DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, p.DateAndTime), 0), v.VehicleID
HAVING SUM(p.NoOfDays) >= 5
```

Comment: Great, made a few modifications but works great. Thank you for your wizardry good sir. `SELECT DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, p.DateAndTime), 0) AS [Month],
     SUM(p.NoOfDays) As Days, v.VehicleID
FROM tblOverNightPermissions p
INNER JOIN tblOverNightToVehicles v ON p.OverNightID = v.OverNightID
GROUP BY DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, p.DateAndTime), 0), v.VehicleID
HAVING SUM(p.NoOfDays) >= 5
ORDER BY Days DESC`

Comment: @Adrian Just thought of one thing: this will not account for days near the end of the month

Comment: @Adrian both. It only looks at the first day. If NoOfDays is 5, and the first day is the 30th, part of the span runs into next month. This won't account for that.